# Bottom navigation bar disappears while navigating with the url in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

My navigation bar works very well when I click on it. When I try to navigate to the pages with the url such as "http://localhost:5000/#/profile" bottom nav bar disappears. I want my navigation bar to stay in the pages where navigation is possible with it. I think I should add the nav bar somehow to the profile page too, but I couldn't find it out.

```
const String HomeRoute = '/';
const String ProfileRoute = '/profile';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: DbProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: ThemeChanger(ThemeData.light()),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialAppWithTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: HomeRoute,
      routes: {
        HomeRoute: (context) => HomePage(),
        ProfileRoute: (context) => Profile(),
      },
      theme: theme.getTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int menuItem = 0;
  List<Widget> allPages;
  Home home;
  Profile profile;
  Favorites favorites;
  Offers offer;

  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User currentUser;
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (mounted) {
      super.initState();
      home = Home();
      profile = Profile();
      favorites = Favorites();
      offer = Offers();
      allPages = [home, offer, favorites, profile];
    }
  }
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: allPages[menuItem],
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavMenu(),
    );
  }

  Theme bottomNavMenu() {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
          canvasColor: Colors.blue.shade900, primaryColor: Colors.orangeAccent),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Main',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_offer),
            label: 'Offer',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outlined),
            label: 'Favs',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        currentIndex: menuItem,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            menuItem = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Profile')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Profile),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bottom navigation bar is included in the Scaffold.

Therefore, it is only present in the HomePage widget.
You should have a navigation bar in your ProfilePage > Scaffold widget as well if you want it to be displayed.

You may need a controller to set the selected index so that all 'main' widgets have access to the current index (or use a provider for example).

Alternative solution, you pass the current index with the route.